# Access My Google Calendar Data using ClientLogin don't work

Tags: authentication, calendar, google-calendar-api, google-authentication

I writed a App want get My Calendar data in backgroud. don't use OAuth, I select [ClientLogin](https://github.com/Ajnasz/GoogleClientLogin) My Code:

```
 var options = {
   url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList',
   headers: {
     'Authorization': 'GoogleLogin auth=' + googleAuth.getAuthId(),
   }
 };

 function callback(error, response, body) {
  console.log(error, response.statusCode);
  console.log(body);
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      var info = JSON.parse(body);
      console.log(info.stargazers_count + " Stars");
      console.log(info.forks_count + " Forks");
  }
}

request(options, callback);
```

Get AuthId success but get Calendar fail. (ps: 
https://cloud.google.com/console/project Calendar API is on)

```
 authId:  DQAAANMAAAAOLw3WZOuW57hXVk-mso4WwZGgH8lrCB4GCwORm_qwGgQbj51aaAZSghuxSiXs5VWRfpMcBkMa9_M0JQDp4ee5Od6iJEtsh48n6WDTciTDGNVxSb90tv9DDX-Bo8T2nOCQC702iwHAOoheOlNf6bF23hsnEJc4IJ8zksP5da9FCz1WtR8X_BpgQl51FE34jLIzaHTKEirVw-Fbpquj4HHRmhql3NSmZGNLiIehYCh77oEwxK1Cv8fT6d9_IXtnzzUkq_aRYgddJ9W8HSDS4CnjMsdxU27aur6D1eINRPV9eA
null 403
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
       "domain": "usageLimits",
       "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
       "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
       "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
      }
   ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
  }
 }
```